# Web scraping a HTML list with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a html list in python to return the list link.

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item-362992" id="menu-item-362993"><a href="https://www.test.com/">test</a></li>
<li class ="menu-item-362994" id="menu-item-362995"><a href="https://www.test2.com/">test2</a></li>
<li class ="menu-item-362995" id="menu-item-362996"><a href="https://www.test3.com/">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do i extract the href link of each one?

```
quotes = []

table = table.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'sub-menu'})

for row in table.find_all('li', attrs={'class'}):
    quote = {}
    quote['url'] = row.a['href']
    quotes.append(quote)

for i in quotes:
   print(i)
```

How do i return each li class without specifying the individual id?

Comment: Once you have the `li`, simply access the `attrs['href']`of its child.

Comment: Maybe you will like beautifulsoup4, check that out , would be some thing like bs.find_all('tr') , then find('a'). get ('href')

Comment: Hey!, it'll be good if you consider accepting or upvoting an answer to reward those who helped you, or if there is something wrong you could leave a comment too ;) @RyanGadsdon

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
quotes = []

for row in table.find_all('li'):
    quote = {}
    quote['url'] = row.a['href']
    quotes.append(quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try this:

```
quotes = []

table = table.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'sub-menu'})

for row in table.find_all('li'):
    quote = {}
    quote[row.attrs['class'][0]] = row.a['href']
    quotes.append(quote)
#Same as: (list comprehension version) 
#table = table.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'sub-menu'})

#quotes=[{row.attrs['class'][0]:row.a['href']} for row in table.find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
quotes
[{'menu-item-362992': 'https://www.test.com/'}, {'menu-item-362994': 'https://www.test2.com/'}, {'menu-item-362995': 'https://www.test3.com/'}]
```

---

Or if you want separate lists:

```
table = table.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'sub-menu'})

quotes=[{'url':row.a['href']} for row in table.find_all('li')]

ilclassnames=[row.attrs['class'][0] for row in table.find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
quotes
[{'url': 'https://www.test.com/'}, {'url': 'https://www.test2.com/'}, {'url': 'https://www.test3.com/'}]

ilclassnames
['menu-item-362992', 'menu-item-362994', 'menu-item-362995']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way to find them but i don't know how you want to marge them or list them.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlresponse, 'lxml')
links = soup.select('ul.sub-menu li a')
for link in links:
    print('url:', link.get('href'))
liclass = soup.select('ul.sub-menu li')
for lc in liclass:
    print(lc.get('class'))
```